# Android Mqtt Publisher app stops unexpectedly

Tags: android, eclipse, mqtt

New to MQTT protocol. My code is working fine on eclipse platform. Now, trying to write publisher mqtt client for android and subscriber is running on eclipse. App is getting closed after launch. Please help me in the following code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
{
  String text="HELOOO";
  TextView  textReply;
  private MqttClient client;
  public static final String TOPIC = "data";
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    try {
      client = new MqttClient("http://IP-address:1883",     MqttClient.generateClientId());
    } catch (MqttException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    try {
      client.connect();

      MqttMessage mssg=new MqttMessage();
      mssg.setPayload(text.getBytes());

      client.disconnect();

    } catch (MqttException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }

  }
}
```

Changes made after @arjun suggestions

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String text="HELOOO";
TextView  textReply;
private MqttClient client;
public static final String TOPIC = "iot_data";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Publisher myClientTask = new Publisher();
    myClientTask.execute();



}
}
class Publisher  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
String text="helloo";
@Override

protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    try {
        MqttClient client = new MqttClient("tcp://Ip:1883", MqttClient.generateClientId());
        client.connect();
        MqttMessage mssg=new MqttMessage();
        mssg.setPayload(text.getBytes());
        client.publish("iot_data",mssg);
        client.disconnect();
    }catch(Exception e)
    {


    }


    return null;
}
```

}

Comment: most likely the app is crashing and you have a System.exit(1) in the catch block. Check the logs and share the same

Comment: Remove the `System.exit()` calls, and update the question with the log output. Also the URL should not start with `http://` it should most likely be `tcp://`

Comment: you are trying to do network operation on main thread. that may crash the app. see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/6343166/2809326

Comment: I tried for tcp also...but not working

Comment: @arjun how should i chng my code. Can u please suggest

Comment: before I give any suggestion, if you can post the error log it will be helpful in debugging

Comment: @hardillb Since i'm running it on phone so how can i find log files?

Comment: @arjun where can i get those error logs

Comment: The logs should be available in Android Studio/eclipse or via the adb tool.

Comment: @arjun I've changed my code as suggested by u still  not working

Comment: You're throwing the exception away without anyway to see what it was and you still haven't included any logs

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has to do with that you are not specifying an ip adress properly on the client which leads to an exception where you do a system.exit(1);

Comment: The IP format is working for eclipse so it must be correct. "tcp:IP_address:1883"

Comment: yes but "tcp://IP_address:1883" is not a valid address what is IP_address in this case, it should be a address to somewhere. So if you are using a test broker for example the one hivemq has the address should be "tcp://broker.hivemq.com:1883"

Comment: Address is valid as i've tested it using already built MQTT clients available on playstore.

Comment: We can also use IP address of the Mosquitto broker instead.